# How to assign the value of 0 to a variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

Javascript function 1:

```
var count = 0;

function myFunction()
{
count++;
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=count;
}
```

Javascript function 2:

```
function demo() {
var y=document.getElementById("count").innerHTML;
if(y=="0") {
alert("There's nothing to be reset.");
}
else {
var count=0;
alert("Reset.");
// alternative code I used: document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="0";
}
}
```

HTML code:

```
<a href="Javascript:myFunction()">Click here</a>
<p>Total:<span id="count">0</span></p>
<button onclick="demo()">reset</button>
```

Is there a way to reset the variable to 0 in this code?

I've tried to reset the variable `count` to zero using `document.getElementById()` and adding `=0;` to the variable. Neither of these work. For example, if the user was to click the link the count would increase to 1. When they click the reset button it would appear to reset to 0 (unless using `var count=0;). However, if the user were to click the link again the count would be return the value 2, as it could simply continue to increment from the previous time.

I'm sorry if this has already been answered somewhere else, but it's very difficult to search for the terms `=` and `++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Get rid of `var` where you reset the variable. That's giving you a separate local variable with the same name.
2. Using "count" as a variable name, if it's global, will cause problems if you've also got an element whose id is "count" in the DOM.  Use a different variable name or a different id, or make sure that the variable is not global (can't tell from posted code).

Answer (score 2):

You made it a local variable by using `var`

```
else {
    var count=0;
    alert("Reset.");
```

should be

```
else {
    count=0;
    alert("Reset.");
```

Answer (score 0):

The things you need to chnage in the code are:

And make the comparison to

```
   if(parseInt(y) === 0) // You are converting it to integer and doing a strict check
```

the else construct to

```
  else {
    count = 0;
    alert('Reset');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not entirely sure what `parseInt(y)===` part does, but I'll add it now. edit: thanks.

Comment: @LiamB parseInt(y) converts it to integer and === is for comparison in javascript